# How can i bind the element name of a different grid column source

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a question regarding the binding element name from a DevExpress grid.

I have an example code:

```
<dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    <dxg:GridColumn  x:Name="colAccountCode" Header="Column 1" FieldName="Account_Id" Width="200">
        <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
            <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings AutoComplete="True" ImmediatePopup="True"
                ValueMember="Account_Id" DisplayMember="Account_Code" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding GetAccounts}"/>
        </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
    </dxg:GridColumn>
    <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="colAccountName" Header="Column Name 1"  FieldName="Account_Id" AllowEditing="False" Width="200">
        <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
            <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings AutoComplete="True" ImmediatePopup="True"
                ValueMember="Account_Id" DisplayMember="Account_Name" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding GetAccounts}"/>
        </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
    </dxg:GridColumn>
</dxg:GridControl.Columns>
```

My question is can I bind the `ItemsSource` property on `Column 1` to the items source on `Column Name 1`, because it is basically the same data. I know there is a binding scheme called "binding by element name", but somehow I could not make it work with this one.

Comment: Thanks DmitryG first time using this StackOverflow caught up in creating the <code> :P

Comment: You are always welcome.

Comment: Bind the itemssource to a collection (with notification implementation) instead of to a method

Comment: @AminBudianto the ItemsSource it self is an ObservableCollection so that means is a collection with notification implemented right?, can i just bind it one time on the column 1 and use element binding for the second items source based on the first column items source?.

Comment: yea you can do something like this ItemsSource={Binding ElementName=colAccountCode, Path=ItemsSource}

Comment: @AminBudianto okay i will try :)